# What do I have to do to prove disjointness?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory

I have $B$ which is a Basis of $V$. I also have asubspace of $V$ which is $U$. For the subspace's Basis I have $B_U\subseteq B$.

Then I also have the Theorem which says that if $B=B_U\dot\cup B_W$ is a Basis of a vectorspace $V$. And $B_U,B_W$ is a Basis of the vectorspaces  $U,W$ respectively. Then I can  say that $V=U\oplus W$.

There is a Statement of a proof that I don't understand,

it says if I define $W$ as $<B\backslash B_U>$ then I can say by the Theorem which I just stated that $V=U\oplus W$

I understand that $B\backslash B_U$ is a Basis of $W$, however a condition to use the Theorem is that both Basis must be disjoint.

First of all why is $B_U\cup B\backslash B_U=B$

and second why is

$B_U\cap(B\backslash B_U)=\emptyset$
?

Thank you so much for reading and maybe helping.

Comment: This is just elementary set theory: the set difference of $B$ and $B_U$ is the set that contains all the elements of $B$ that are not in $B_U$. Since $B_U$ is a subset of B in this case, the two properties follow trivially. Draw a Venn diagram if you are still confused.

Answer (score 1):

We will explicitly use set theory definitions:

$B = \left\{ v \in V \, | \, v \in B \right\}$

$B_U = \left\{ v \in V \, | \, v \in B_U \right\}$

$B\setminus B_U = \left\{ v \in V \, | \, v \in B \mbox{ and } v \notin B_U\right\}$

From here we can adress your questions:

$B \cup (B\setminus B_U) = \left\{ v \in V \, | \, (v\in B) \mbox{ or } (v \in B \mbox{ and } v \notin B_U) \right\} = \left\{ v \in V \, | \, v \in B \right\} = B$

$B_U \cap (B\setminus B_U) = \left\{ v \in V \, | \, (v\in B_U) \mbox{ and } (v \in B \mbox{ and } v \notin B_U) \right\} = \left\{ v \in V \, | \, (v\in B_U) \mbox{ and } (v \notin B_U) \right\} = \emptyset$

Comment: The Problem is what if $v\in B \text{ and } v\in B_U$? Why can I just delete the Information $v\in B_U$?

Comment: Which of the 5 definition are you confused about?  To answer your question, if $v\in B$ and $v\in B_U$, then $v\in B\cap B_U$.  Also, I would suggest, as the other commenter did, to draw venn diagrams for all those 5 definitions so you can visualize it!